# Duplicate gradle dependencies always compiled?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

If i have say the `appcompat-v7` dependency in my build.gradle and then I have another dependency that also uses the `appcompat-v7` library are both of those compiled or is just one compiled and the other is ignored?

Reason I ask is I ran the gradle command that gives you your dependency tree and there were a lot of duplicated dependencies that are in other libraries but already declared in my app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradle resolves the dependencies according to some rules:

1. If they have the same version number, there is no problem and the dependency is added once with the given version number.
2. If they are imported twice with different version number, gradle uses a default conflict strategy to choose the "best one".

In all case, a given library is always added only once.